# Display mysql database report in several pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql database with some data. Now i want to show you mysql data to all. with edit option.

```
<?php

$username = "VKSolutions";

$password = "VKSolutions@1";

$hostname = "VKSolutions.hostedresource.com";

$database = "VKSolutions";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)

 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle)

 or die("Could not select $database");

$query= 'SELECT * FROM customer_details';

$result = mysql_query($query)

or die ('Error in query');

echo '<table width=80% border=1 align="center">';

echo '<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Name</b></td><td width="25px">    <b>Telephone</b></td><td width="30px"><b>E-mail</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Country     Applying for</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Visa Categeory</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Other     Categeory</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Passport No</b></td><td width="50px">    <b>Remarks</b></td></tr>';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))

{

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[2].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[3].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[4].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[5].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[6].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[7].'</td>';

echo '<td>'.$row[8].'</td>';

echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

mysql_free_result($result);

mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

I need some modifications in this code like

1) MySql data displays in a single page. but not i want. I need to display data with several pages like (page1,page2,page3,.....page54... etc)

2) and also give edit option when a user want to change.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add pagination.

Comment: what did you try and what went wrong, for code examples search on google. so you can learn something of it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add LIMIT to your select statement.

If you read here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

So you would change your statement to:
SELECT * FROM customer_details LIMIT 0,20

This would get the first 20 records, then to get the next lot of results:
SELECT * FROM customer_details LIMIT 20,20

The numbers after the limit are, the first one is where it still start and the second one is how many to return.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Your remaining data is not obtained. As you told it to pull the first 20 records. You need to change the limits for the next page, so you would put 20,20 for page 2. For page 3 it would be 40,20 and so on. Does this make sense?

Comment: This is not possible. In this way every time we need to change. The correct answer is pagination. so i need some code for pagination with out removing this code.

Comment: Pagination is the correct answer, I  was showing you how to get the SQL statement correct in order for pagination to work. You don't want to pull the whole list down at once, that would increase page load times of you had thousands of records. Using limit shows you how to select the right amount of data for each page. You then code php to build the page numbers that change the limits depending on the page. When I'm home I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Did a quick Google, here is what I am trying to explain:

Answer (score 0):

hey if you want to show data with pages use pagination also if you want to edit the value than you have to show data in a text box like this and send via form

```
<?php

$username = "VKSolutions";

 $password = "VKSolutions@1";

 $hostname = "VKSolutions.hostedresource.com";

 $database = "VKSolutions";

 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)

   or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

 $selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle)

 or die("Could not select $database");

 $query= 'SELECT * FROM customer_details';

 $result = mysql_query($query)

  or die ('Error in query');
?>

  <table width=80% border=1 align="center" id=pag>

<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Name</b></td><td width="25px"><b>Telephone</b></td><td width="30px">    <b>E-mail</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Country     Applying for</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Visa Categeory</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Other Categeory</b></td><td width="20px"><b>Passport No</b></td><td width="50px"><b>Remarks</b></td></tr>

<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
?>
<tr>

<td><input type="text" name="newid" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="newname" value="<?php echo $row[1];?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aaaa" value="<?php echo $row[2];?>" /></td>
......

 </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>
//pagination code
<div class="pagination" align="center" >
        <div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
      </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var pager = new Pager('pag',10); // pag is id of table and 10 is no of records you want to show in a page. you can change if you want
    pager.init(); 
    pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
    pager.showPage(1);
   //--></script>
 </div> 
<?php
mysql_free_result($result);

mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

in the head section add this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="paging.js"></script> /* adding javascript pagination source page */
```

code for paging.js goes here. just copy and paste the code in a file name paging.js

```
    function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
           else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
        this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

        var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span>   &nbsp;&nbsp; ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++) 
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page   + ');">' + page + '</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';            

        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to add a form before table so that you can edit. I have edited  some part of my code try it. I have used it several times